# How to change Tiptap wrapper to React?

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, tiptap

what needs to be fixed to remove the extra wrapper `div`, or how to add styles for it?

```
import {useEditor, EditorContent} from '@tiptap/react'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'

export default function Editor() {
    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [
            StarterKit,
        ],
        content: 'test',
    })

    return <EditorContent editor={editor} />;
}
```

result

```html
<div>
    <div contenteditable="true" translate="no" class="ProseMirror" tabindex="0">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected Result

```html
<div class="my">
    <div contenteditable="true" translate="no" class="ProseMirror" tabindex="0">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```html
<div contenteditable="true" translate="no" class="ProseMirror" tabindex="0">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```